# Equivalent of Mongrel/Webrick for PHP Development?

Tags: php

Is there an equivalent in PHP development to using Mongrel/Webrick during Rails development?

I normally use Mongrel on port 3000 to serve up my Rails app during development.

Its been a couple of years since I've done PHP development. From what I recall, the method was to run Apache on the dev machine during PHP development (which involved setting up virtual domain in Apache etc....).

Is this still the case or is there a simpler method these days. Unfortunately a quick Google did not yield anything of interest.

Before I forget, the dev environment is on Debian Lenny. Ubuntu solutions also welcome.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a look at [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) - that's quick & easy to install and configure with PHP.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. I'd forgotten about Lightty.

Comment: so is there a way quickly serve a directory just by running some command and without any configuration file?

Comment: You could add a script to automagically edit the lighttpd.conf file to add a virtual server based on that directory and bounce the lighttpd process.  With lighttpd you do need that configuration file though.

Answer (score 7):

I found interesting answer on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/258835/webrick-like-php-server):

> A built-in [webserver](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver) will be included in a future version of PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Debian/Ubuntu it's fairly easy to set up an Apache environment. Everything you need is in Synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how to do it in ubuntu, but if you want really easy, use a VM appliance:
[LAMP appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lamp).

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) may also be workable, but I have only used that in windows.

In ubuntu:

sudo tasksel

select LAMP, and that will set up apache, etc. In the middle of the install it will ask for the mysql password.

Files live within /var/www, but this can easily be changed in vhosts (I use a subdirectory of my home folder which is more often backed up). A quick check of the ubuntu online documentation should show you the correct files to edit (since I think there was a change after hardy).

Subversion and phpmyadmin are a good idea as well, as I'm sure you are aware.

a2enmod will enable mod-rewrite, etc, as that is not enabled by default