# php webserver equivalent of mongrel?

Tags: php

Is there a php equivalent of mongrel? I don't want to install Apache, just to preview a simple template.

Comment: You can take a look at this question for another solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297054/equivalent-of-mongrel-webrick-for-php-development

Comment: Yeah just saw that one, vote to close - this is a dup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible starting with php 5.4:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

> As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.
>
> This web server is designed for developmental purposes only, and
>   should not be used in production.

To run it:

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 2):

mongrel2 looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the ideal solution, but if it's just one page, you can render it straight out to HTML.

```
php /path/to/file.php > /path/to/output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in the other thread - have a look at Photon (http://www.photon-project.com), it might serve your needs quite well already.